# Access forbidden! You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

while using $_SERVER in php i am getting this error 403.

i am using three files

index.php:-

```
<?php

    include 'header.inc.php';

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        echo 'process 1';
    }

    ?>
```

header.inc.php:-

```
<?php

$_script_name= $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];


?>

<form action="<?php echo $script_name ?>" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="log in">
</form>
```

another.inc.php:-

```
<?php
include 'header.inc.php';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    echo 'process 2';
}

?>
```

after clicking of log in button i displayed the page with error 403

[this is the page  showing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSOe5.png)

please help me hoe to solve this problem. I am searching for the correct solution for last 2 days but didnt find any working solution.

Comment: Take a look at the URL in your screenshot. That looks pretty unhealthy. Check what `<?php echo $script_name ?>` actually outputs, so your form action, most likely that is the issue. Easiest is to use the browsers development console for that, "inspect" the `<form>` element.

Comment: I assume <?php echo $script_name ?> should be <?php echo $_script_name; ?> and you should add name="submit" attribute to your submit button.

Comment: Can you post your .htaccess? I'd this code in a subfolder of your web root? Does a dummy index.html file work?